# Local variable on a background thread together with Dispatcher.Invoke

Tags: wpf, thread-safety, dispatcher

In a method running on a background thread, if I have a local variable that I need to update from within the UI thread (Dispatcher.Invoke), do I need to lock it?

```
private void OnTimerTick(...)
    {
        bool local = false;

        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            local = true;
        }));

        if (local) return;
    }
```

Since the handler could be called while control is inside the Invoke call, I wasn't sure what the best way of doing this safely. I absolutely need to set "local" from within the UI thread.

Comment: Looks like you might have a wait screen or updating, but the `Dispatcher` should take care of that. Have you had any problems with the local variable being deadlocked?

Comment: not yet ;-) Wanted to make sure it can't deadlock

Comment: Have a look at this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) article it should help you understand what exactly the Dispatcher does.